# Can someone explain how this code works with range and slicing?

Tags: python-3.x

```
s = 'eljwboboblejr'  # dont paste into grader
count = 0
for i in range (len(s)): 
    if s[i:i+3]== 'bob':
        count+=1 
print('Number of times bob occurs is: ' + str(count))
```

I do not get how len is working here, or if s[i:i+3] == 'bob'

Answer (score 0):

So what happens here is that the `i` goes through all the letters, and slice all the letters by `i` and `i+3` in each loop. What `len` is doing is just taking the length of `s` (basically how many characters there are in it) and returning it as an integer. What the `s[i:i+3] == 'bob'` is doing is determining if the sliced string is equal to `'bob'`. So imagine that the `i` represents all the letters in the `s` string. So if the sliced string that is contained by the `i` and `i+3` has 'bob' in it, it returns true. It's not the greatest of explanations, but I hope it helps.

Comment: so when I did for i in range len(s)), that declared a variable of 'i' and the variable has all the strings of 's' in it. With that being said, whats [i:i+3] doing? I

Answer (score 0):

documentation for len is here:
https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html#len

It will be implemented in string as a magic private function (__len__, I believe).

documentation for range is here:
https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html#range

With one arg, range generates integers 0 to that arg (excluding arg itself).

The slice in the loop  evaluates to 'elj', then 'ljw', then 'jwb', ... in subsequent iterations. The slice [a:b] doesn't include the b'th element.